# Using sed with back-references calculated

Tags: shell, perl, sed

I would like

```
pm.max_children = 5
```

to become;

```
pm.max_children = 8
```

and have been working on it and got no soludtions. Backreferences like \1 or \2 don't seem to be working with calculation.

```
sed -i -E "s/(pm.max_children)[^=]*=\s*(.+)/\1 = $(echo \2+3)/" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Using perl commands are OK as well as long as it is solved.

Thank you.

Comment: I have got more to that... a shell variable is not calculated with backreference-values..
```
php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory=$(printenv PHP_FPM_ALLOCATED_GB_MEMORY)
export php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory
perl -i.bak -wpe"s/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/$1 * $php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory/e" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```
That returns this strange message..

Argument "*main::2" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1, <> line 113.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108917/7344596 has saved my day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -i.bak -wpe's/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/$1 + 3/e' file
```

This keeps a backup due to [`.bak`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-i%5Bextension%5D); remove that (after testing) if you don't need a backup.

The [`\K` positive lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK) drops all previous matches so that they are no longer included in the overall match `$&`, and thus whatever has been matched before it is kept in the string and doesn't have to be restored in the replacement part.

Comment: I didn't know Perl at all but you saved my day! Thanks.

Comment: I have got more to that... a shell variable is not calculated with backreference-values..

php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory=$(printenv PHP_FPM_ALLOCATED_GB_MEMORY)
export php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory
perl -i.bak -wpe"s/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/$1 * $php_fpm_allocated_gb_memory/e" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

That returns strange values

Comment: @KangAndrew I see that's been resolved in another question, right?  --> Use single quotes, and then there are (three) clear ways to pass variables from the shell to perl.

Comment: Right. you two were a great help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(.* \)\(.*\)/echo \1 \$((\2+3))/e' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
pm.max_children = 8
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? that doesn't work there is no even 'pm.max_children' in the string

Comment: @KangAndrew The code provided does not need literals such as `pm.max_children` unless you have a need to match those strings as it matches your example sample to the last space in the first back reference and the integer in the second. Return them, we can calculate the numerics. If your data is in a different format from the sample provided, it will fail. If so, provide testable samples for me to fix the regex

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, this is one of them:

```
perl -lpe 's/(?<= = )(\d)/${1}+3/e' <<< 'pm.max_children = 5'
```

for exact match:

```
perl -lpe 's/pm.max_children = \K(\d)/${1}+3/e' <<< 'pm.max_children = 5'
```

just match a number at the end:

```
perl -lpe 's/(\d)$/${1}+3/e' <<< 'pm.max_children = 5'
```

output:

```
pm.max_children = 8
```

---

For files, you can use `-i` in-place saving and instead of `<<<` (here document which is for testing) use a file.

```
perl -i -lpe '...' <FILE>
```