# Perl string replace with backreferenced values and shell variables

Tags: shell, perl

Let's say 'pm.max_children = 8' on the file '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf'
The result of the following is supposed to be 40 but $1 is just ignored.

```
aaa=5
perl -i.bak -e "s/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/($1 * $aaa)/ge" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

But the strange thing is the following is working, in case $aaa is not a variable.

```
perl -i.bak -e "s/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/($1 * 3)/ge" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Comment: `$1` is a positional argument, that expands to _nothing_ if not passed. How are you invoking this ? in a script..? in a function..?

Comment: In a shell script.  That is related to this one.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72107849/using-sed-with-back-references-calculated

Comment: The answer clearly demonstrated using single quotes there to represent the first matching group. `$1` in double quotes is expanded under the context of shell and not in the context of perl

Comment: Neither do Single quotes.. um...

Comment: The `$1` is replaced here by the calling shell, not by Perl. The effect depens on how you invoke your shell script. I suggest that you do a `set -x` in your script, so that you can observe what's actually going on. You need to make up your mind, which variables should be expanded by Perl (they need to be escaped or be inside single quotes to prevent shell expansion) and which one should be expanded by the shell (they need to be insided double quotes, to cause shell expansion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `$1` is different in the shell and in Perl.

In the shell, it means the first positional argument. As double quotes expand variables, `$1` in double quotes also means the first positional argument.

In Perl, `$1` means the first capture group matched by a regular expression.

But, if you use `$1` in double quotes on the shell level, Perl never sees it: the shell expands `$1` as the first positional argument and sends the expanded string to Perl.

You can use the `%ENV` hash in Perl to refer to environment variables:

```
aaa=5 perl -i.bak -pe 's/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/($1 * $ENV{aaa})/ge' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Comment: That is amazing. Finally this has worked out.

aaa=8
export aaa
perl -i.bak -pe 's/pm.max_children\s*=\s*\K([0-9]+)/($1 * $ENV{aaa})/ge' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Comment: You don't have to `export` the variable. If you assign it on the same line as the command, it's exported to the command only, as shown in the answer.

Comment: oh... I see. I set it on the different line That is why it didn't work. $ENV seems like same as printenv in Bash. That way I load envs directly that a docker-compose.yml passes.

Comment: @choroba But if you put it on the same line, where is the benefit from using a shell variable in Perl and invoking all this trouble in the first place? Then just put the variable in Perl from the start.

Comment: @TLP There's no really "simple" way to put a shell variable into `perl -p`.

Comment: @TLP  Correct. On second thought, that could make sense as well.